# FileBrowser callback instead of popup with CKEditor 4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, ckeditor

I use CKEditor in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, but I am still on version 4.0.2 because I am using the `fileBrowserCallback` config by using the patch from [AlexW](https://github.com/Alex-Code/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/filebrowser/plugin.js) (see also [here](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6085)). But this patch is not compatible with any newer version.

Now with the new release of CKEditor 4.5 I finally would like to upgrade as they have some great new features (like drag&drop/copy&paste upload), but I do not want to go back to the "pop-up file-browser".
I searched the docs and APIs for all the new file-browser plugins/options, but I still can't find such an option.
**Did I miss a config option to enable this or is it still not possible?**

If not is there an "updated patch" around which adds it again or can someone point me to the location I could add it on my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to patch CKEditor to have your custom callback called when the Browse Server button is pressed. Check the following sample code that alters the Image dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Browse server - custom callback</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="sample_posteddata.php" method="post">
        <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">

        </textarea>
        <script>

            CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
                // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
                var dialogName = ev.data.name;
                var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

                // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
                // interested on (the "Image" dialog).
                if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
                    // Get a reference to the "Image Properties" tab.
                    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

                    // Get a reference to the "Browse Server" button.
                    var browse = infoTab.get( 'browse' );
                    // Instruct filebrowser plugin to skip hooking into this button.
                    browse[ 'filebrowser' ] = false;
                    // The "Browse Server" button is hidden by default.
                    browse[ 'hidden' ] = false;
                    // Add our own callback.
                    browse[ 'onClick' ] = function() {
                        var url = prompt( 'Type some URL' );
                        this.getDialog().getContentElement( 'info', 'txtUrl' ).setValue( url );
                    };
                }
            } );

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```